# Pandas: how do I vectorise a multi-column filter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I would like to efficiently filter a dataframe according to values in multiple columns.

I have this dataframe:

| index | type | group | home |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | offence | 1 | home |
| b | offence | 2 | home |
| c | offence | 2 | away |
| d | offence | 3 | home |
| e | defence | 3 | away |

I want to identify the rows preceding a row with type `defence` that have `group` **equal to or one less than** the `defence` row, and whose `home` value is not the same as the `defence` row. e.g. for the above:

| index | type | group | home |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | offence | 2 | home |
| d | offence | 3 | home |

So I want to return `['b', 'd']`.

This is easy if iterating:

```py
return_rows = []
for _, def_row in df[df['type'] == 'defence'].iterrows():
    this_iloc = df.index.get_loc(def_row.name)
    while True:
        this_iloc -= 1
        if this_iloc <= 0:
            break
        this_row = df.iloc[this_iloc]
        if this_row['group'] < def_row['group'] - 1:
            break
        if this_row['home'] != def_row['home']:
            return_rows.append(this_row.name)
```

I can now set these rows using `df.loc[df.index.isin(return_rows)]`

I would like to do this vectorized, without iterating.

I would start like this, under the assumption that the rows in question will be at most 5 rows back:

```py
for i in range(1, 6):
    df = pd.concat([df, df.shift(i).add_suffix(str(i))], axis=1)
return_rows = df[
    (df['group1'] >= df['group'] - 1 & df['home1'] != df['home']) | 
    (df['group2'] >= df['group'] - 1 & df['home2'] != df['home']) |
    ... (etc.)
]
```

However, this would return the `defence` rows, and I actually want to return the rows preceding `defence` rows.

How do I do this in a vectorised way?

Answer (score 3):

Try with `shift`

```
out = df[df.home.eq('away').shift(-1).dropna() & df.home.ne('away') ]
Out[376]: 
  index     type  group  home
1     b  offence      2  home
3     d  offence      3  home
```

Update

```
s = df.home.eq('away').groupby(df.group).idxmax()-1
df.loc[s[s>=0]]
Out[384]: 
  index     type  group  home
1     b  offence      2  home
3     d  offence      3  home
```

Comment: Or `shift(-1, fill_value=False)`.

Comment: @BENY Thank you, though this does not cover the requirements on the value of `group`